# Java: Eclipse console doesn't display Spring Controller information

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, servlets

When I run my spring boot application in eclipse 4.7.3 IDE, the console doesn't display the information about the rest controller. Nevertheless the controller is working when I test it with browser.

It is just a "Hello World" application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldSpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

}


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String helo() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-28 09:08:33.768  INFO 2208 --- [           main] c.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp   : Starting HelloWorldSpringBootApp on OfficeLaptop01 with PID 2208 (C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace4.7.3a\Sprang\HelloWorldSpringBoot\target\classes started by Admin in C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-workspace4.7.3a\Sprang\HelloWorldSpringBoot)
2019-04-28 09:08:33.775  INFO 2208 --- [           main] c.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-28 09:08:34.852  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-28 09:08:34.873  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-28 09:08:34.873  INFO 2208 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-28 09:08:34.978  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-28 09:08:34.978  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1157 ms
2019-04-28 09:08:35.183  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-28 09:08:35.348  INFO 2208 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-28 09:08:35.351  INFO 2208 --- [           main] c.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp   : Started HelloWorldSpringBootApp in 1.904 seconds (JVM running for 2.561)
```

As above it just display until "Started HelloWorldSpringBootApp in 1.904 seconds" without the request mapping status & mapped URL path info. Why?

Comment: try debug level log and for what information you are looking exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [log output was changed in Spring 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements). That changelog states that

> If you are trying to debug an application and you want to restore
>   Spring Boot 2.0 style logging you should add the following to your
>   `application.properties`

```
logging.level.web=debug
```

This change however does not output what I would expect given this `RestController`

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

If I set the log level to `trace` it gives the expected output (though not in the exact same way as Spring Boot 2.1).

```
10:53:26.427 [main] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - 
    c.i.e.d.r.HelloWorldController:
    { /hello}: hello()
```

The requirement for `trace` log level is most likely due to a change in Spring Framework 5.1 (see [release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x))